# Lm7812 circuit help

Tags: capacitor, lm78xx

In [image: this] circuit to get a steady 12v DC I don't understand the use of the capacitors. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Actually can someone tell me how the whole circuit works?

Comment: 1) that's not a circuit, a circuit looks like: http://www.circuitdiagram.org/12v-power-supply-circuit.html  2) the capacitors are needed to remove the ripple from the rectified AC and the small one on the output is needed by the LM7812 to prevent oscillations. 3) Don't add comments with an extra question, instead **edit** your question. 4) how the whole circuit works: there can be plenty information found if you search the internet, search for: "linear power supply"

Comment: You could at least show that you have tried to find an answer. This is really a simple question and google should return dozens of excellent answers. And, PLEASE, don't post Fritzing like pictures. This is not an electrical circuit.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a circuit...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f15x5M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I believe this is what the "sketch" is showing.

A centre-tapped XFMR to step down 230V to say ... 12Vac.  A full-wave recifier to produce "DC". The 1st electrolytic is used to smooth the output of the rectifier. The regulator to produce a usable smooth DC and finally an output capacitor to provide decoupling, tank for charge etc.